# How to load apk on device file system and start

Tags: android, apk

I need to know how to load an application into a tablet where all I can do is a file transfer into the file storage area.  I am using a tablet that does not have good eclipse usb integration, but I can put the file somewhere on the device, can someone please indicate where I need to place the apk and steps to load it after that.  It is android 2.1 tablet Thanks

Comment: fab is correct (especially remembering to enable "Unknown sources". If you have an SD card then I'd recommend /sdcard/download or /sdcard/downloads depending on your file system (I have both folders on my v2.2 device - not sure if that's the case for v2.1)

Comment: Ok.  Its sitting on /sdcard/download  what are the next step to install on the phone?

Comment: guys please be specific about what to do after APK is at right location on device.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the apk somewhere on your file system and open it with a file manager (ASTRO for example) in order to install it.
You have to activate "Settings" -> "Applications" -> "Unknown source" before.

Comment: Tell me more about how opening with ASTRO would install it?

Comment: Please clarify about the install steps aft placing the file on android file system. Thanks

Comment: ASTRO is just a file manager. You browse through your file system to the place where your apk is. When you click on the apk file, ASTRO will know that this is an application to install and tries to find a suitable installer program. Then the default Android app install will open and ask you if you want to install the apk.

Comment: A even shorter way: Use an 3rd party app Installer (AppMonster for example). So you don't need an extra file manager.

Comment: Please be specific my friends about how the installation takes place after putting file in the right place on the device

Comment: whats the deal with astro. Does Windows Explorer work for this?

Comment: @Androider: It's quite simple...Astro is an Android app...it's free...go to the App Market and search for Astro...install it...it's a file manager/explorer app...open Astro...find your /sdcard/download directory...touch the apk file...Astro will automatically fire up the appmanager which will install the apk. DONE!

Comment: Thanks fab, ASTRO app worked for me. I used Android File Manager (the window that opens as soon as I hook my device up to my computer via USB) to drag and drop my `apk` file into (anywhere in the window will do), then went to open ASTRO and found the `apk` file in there. Clicked on it and that opened it in my device. It puts the app's icon right on your device desktop so you can open it that way later. I have a Mac OS on my computer.